# jquery ajax callback is not working

Tags: javascript, spring, jquery, callback

i want to get a value through ajax call this is how i have done,

```
<input type="text" id="CIMtrek_CI_CER" name="CIMtrek_CI_CER" onblur="getProjectInfo()"/>
```

and this is what is my script,

```
function getProjectInfo(){
    var cerNo = document.getElementById('CIMtrek_CI_CER').value;
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "CIMtrek_Project_Information",
         data: {
             cerNo: cerNo
         },
         success: function (msg) {
             alert("msg : "+msg);
             document.getElementById('div_CIMtrek_CI_Used_By_ProjNo').innerHTML=msg;
         }
     });
}
```

and this is what is my spring method :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/CIMtrek_Project_Information", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getProjectInfotmation(@RequestParam("cerNo") String cerNo,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("cerNo : "+cerNo);

        return cerNo;
    }
```

controll goes to this method and prints the value also but it does not replicate in call back where i have assigned the value.

```
success: function (msg) {
                 alert("msg : "+msg);
                 document.getElementById('div_CIMtrek_CI_Used_By_ProjNo').innerHTML=msg;
             }
```

when i have used firebug the response is `HTTP Status 404 - /ProjectCapexMonitoring/WEB-INF/views/81723.jsp`

`81723` is the input i gave with this input `.jsp` is added and gives this exception.

Please help me to fine what is the and resolve.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are expecting json response and 
 have jackson jars in your classpath

add `@ResponseBody` to your method

change

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/CIMtrek_Project_Information", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getProjectInfotmation(@RequestParam("cerNo") String cerNo,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("cerNo : "+cerNo);

    return cerNo;
}
```

to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/CIMtrek_Project_Information", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String getProjectInfotmation(@RequestParam("cerNo") String cerNo,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("cerNo : "+cerNo);

    return cerNo;
}
```

Comment: Great it helped me to resolve my problem, will accept your answer in few after few minutes, It is not allowing me to accept :)

Comment: Cool, fixed, i had issue with returning map in ajax,thanks you have answered for that question, do you know xslt ?

Comment: Kris would you please look in to this question `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960498/create-combo-box-in-xslt/14962338#comment21031638_14962338`