# how to test whether the value is zero in xslt 1.0

Tags: if-statement, xslt-1.0, conditional-statements

i have the following condition in my xslt 1.0

```
<xsl:when test="string-length(//Record/CIMtrek_CI_OPEX_200910_FrDiv/text()) != 0" ></xsl:when
```

but this condition is executed even if the value of `CIMtrek_CI_OPEX_200910_FrDiv` is `0`,

i dont want this condition to be executed when the value of `CIMtrek_CI_OPEX_200910_FrDiv` is `0`

how to do this in xslt 1.0

Please help me to get this done.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
test="translate(//Record/CIMtrek_CI_OPEX_200910_FrDiv, '0', '')"
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i was waiting for your response for a long time. Please check this question also `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960498/create-combo-box-in-xslt`